# JobIntentService crashing in above Android O (8) and above after targeting api 26

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, jobintentservice

I had changed target to API 27 (Android O) and migrated IntentService to JobIntentService after that It started crash in some devices on Android O(8) and above.

Here is crash log.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Caller no longer running, last stopped +2s213ms because: timed out while starting
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1943)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
   at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.dequeueWork(IJobCallback.java:191)
   at android.app.job.JobParameters.dequeueWork(JobParameters.java:196)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl.dequeueWork(SourceFile:314)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService.dequeueWork(SourceFile:639)
   at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground$10299ca(SourceFile:2389)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: have you added android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"  to  your service present in manifest.xml?

Comment: Please post the code of services class, manifest,class where you are service class :)

Comment: @Quicklearner you want to add android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" to just JobIntent Service or IntentServices too?

Answer (score 1):

Read here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293 it seems te bo Google bug

Comment: I had seen the issue but what's the solution, Crash graph due to this issue is going high in production.

Comment: Somebody has posted workaround, fixed class. Read bug report and comments

Comment: That class will not fix the issue, If i will place try catch over there then service stuck in infinite loop. That solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. It would be helpful if you provide explanation in your answer, because issue tracker is not publicly available.